# Spring validation aspect vs static method call

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

How would you make a universal class with validation methods in your spring boot app? Let's say you want to create something that's trivial to use, allowing you to check if a certain method should be called? Does making a Validation class with static methods make sense more than creating an aspect? Is it possible to do something like this:

```
@CheckIfICanDoThis(args)
public void DoSomething() {
doing something...
}
```

Comment: It is, but not exactly as written in your example. It's hard to imagine the use of static method comparing to your sample. What would be and where does the "args" come from? Later, how would you like to call the `DoSomething`? Before, after, in the same time when other method is running? For something trivial or single entry point that needs to validate args, I'd go with static. If you want to everytime call the `DoSomething` when args of some other methods are valid I'd go with @Around or @After implemented for you custom annotation.

Comment: For custom validation method in a Spring context I'd go with a @Component over a class with validation methods, so for the trivial (length, notnull) I could use the Spring annotations over validation method parameters. Spring  and other validation libraries comes with nicely defined ways of validating common types of input (eg. lenght, null or email addresses).